# boost deadline_timer issue

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Here follows the implementation of a test class wrapping a thread with a timer.
The strange thing is that if the deadline is set to 500 milliseconds it works but if I set it to 1000 milliseconds it does not. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include "TestTimer.hpp"
#include "../SysMLmodel/Package1/Package1.hpp"

TestTimer::TestTimer(){
    thread = boost::thread(boost::bind(&TestTimer::classifierBehavior,this));
    timer = new      boost::asio::deadline_timer(service,boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
    timer->async_wait(boost::bind(&TestTimer::timerBehavior, this));


};

TestTimer::~TestTimer(){
}

void TestTimer::classifierBehavior(){
 service.run();
};


void TestTimer::timerBehavior(){
std::cout<<"timerBehavior\r";
timer->expires_at(timer->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
timer->async_wait(boost::bind(&TestTimer::timerBehavior,this));
}
```

**UPDATE 1**
I have noticed that the program stucks (or at least the standard output in the console for many seconds, about 30) then a lot of "timerBehavior" strings are printed out together as if they have been queued somewhere.

Comment: You should make sure, that your service isn't running out of work. There is nothing that prevents the thread to get started first and runs service.run() once. Then after the thread ran out of work, the second line of the TestTimer c'tor gets executed.

Comment: @Torsten: I have updated my question with more details. I am using Eclipse with gcc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You program might have several problems. From what you have shown, it's hard to say, if the program stops before the timer had a chance to trigger. And, you do not flush your output, use std::endl, if you want to flush the output after a newline. Third, if your thread is going to run the io_service.run() function, it might be that the thread finds an empty io queue and run() will return immediately. To prevent that, there is a work class, that will prevent this. Here is my example, from you code, that might work as expected:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class TestTimer
{
public:
    TestTimer()
        : service()
        , work( service )
        , thread( boost::bind( &TestTimer::classifierBehavior,this ) )
        , timer( service,boost::posix_time::milliseconds( 1000 ) )
    {
        timer.async_wait( boost::bind( &TestTimer::timerBehavior, this ) );
    }

    ~TestTimer()
    {
        thread.join();
    }
private:
    void classifierBehavior()
    {
        service.run();
    }


    void timerBehavior() {
        std::cout << "timerBehavior" << std::endl;
        timer.expires_at( timer.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds( 1000 ) );
        timer.async_wait( boost::bind( &TestTimer::timerBehavior,this ) );
    }

    boost::asio::io_service         service;
    boost::asio::io_service::work   work;
    boost::thread                   thread;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer     timer;
};

int main()
{
    TestTimer test;
}
```